# Displaying <ul> in two rows instead of one

Tags: html, css

I want to display an unordered list in two rows on the html web page. 
[image]

And I would like it to look like this:
[image]

I can figure out the padding and margins to space out the names. I'm just wondering what methods can be used to split the list into two.

Comment: Please update question with HTML.

Comment: have you tried this? https://csswizardry.com/2010/02/mutiple-column-lists-using-one-ul/

Comment: I would think as you are iterating your list and appending to each ul you could just place all odd indexed values in the left ul and all even indexed values in the right ul, or vice-versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use css grid system

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```css
ul {
  columns: 2;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
</ul>
```